# Regular exprssion for make an alphanumeric value to uppercase

Tags: regex, uppercase, alphanumeric

I have a textfield, and I would like to validate it's text with the following regex: ^([A-Z0-9]{1,40})$.

So this regex accepts only uppercase letters and numbers with maximum 40 length.

But the user can enter in the field letters (lowercase/uppercase), numbers and whitespaces. Before validating the above regex, I want to perform replacements:

For the whitespaces I use:

- fromVale: "\s" -> this will search all whitespace character
- toValue: "" -> replace it with 0 length character

But how can I search in an alphanumeric string for only character(s) and replace it to uppercase? In this case what will be the from value and to value? I try:

- fromVale: "\w" -> this will search all letter
- toValue: "\U" ->  make uppercase

but this isn't work...

Examples of acceptable values: aaa11c1BB222cc -> after replacement: AAA11C1BB222CC

Thanks,
madik

Comment: what language are you using? add that to your tags, please.

Comment: I think it is irrelevent in point of question. If I write a correct rule, it would be work in all high level programing language...

Comment: @madik when it comes to regular expressions that is so not true I'm affraid.

Comment: That would depend on the regular expression engine you're using. POSIX (BRE, ERE)? PCRE? …? And that often enough depends on the language you're using.

Comment: Also, replacement methods are very different in different languages.

Comment: My part is objective c (the other is Java), and I use RegexKitLite. But there is a limitation, the replacement method takes fromValue as a regex, and the toValue as a string, not a regex again. I'm afraid of it is impossible...

Comment: I think the solution will be that use a constant (e.g. UPPERCASE) as fromvalue, and handle this on native side in different way using built in method...

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it *what* is being made uppercase:

```
From: \w
To: \U\0
```

This is saying to make the zeroth group (ie the whole match) uppercase

Comment: Something goes wrong:
String: Wetw1111we22
Replacement fromValue: \w, toValue: \U\0
replacedString: U0U0U0U0U0U0U0U0U0U0U0U0

Comment: Ohh, I get te problem. The native replacement method takes first argument a regex expression, and replaces the match(es) to a string given as second parameter, not to another regex...

Comment: It all depends on what tool you're using. Each tool has its own way of expressing both "uppercase" and "group zero". You might try `\u` instead of `\U` and `$0` instead of `\0`.